# not able to run maven install getting compile time errors as package does not exist can any one help me out

Tags: maven

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    BasicWicketSetup
    BasicWicketSetup
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    BasicWicketSetup
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            axis
            axis
            1.4
        
        
            commons-discovery
            commons-discovery
            0.2
        
        
            axis
            axis-jaxrpc
            1.4
        
        
            xml-resolver
            xml-resolver
            1.2
        
        
            org.apache.xerces
            serializer
            2.9.1
        
        
            org.slf4j
            slf4j-api
            1.5.8
        
        
            org.slf4j
            slf4j-log4j12
            1.4.2
        
        
            org.apache.wicket
            wicket
            1.4.17
        
        
            org.apache.wicket
            wicket
            1.4.9
        
        
            org.apache.wicket
            wicket-extensions
            1.4.9
        
        
            org.wicketstuff.jquery
            wicketstuff-jquery
            1.3.3
        
        
            org.odlabs.wiquery
            wiquery
            1.0.2
        
        
            wsdl4j
            wsdl4j
            1.5.1
        
        
            xerces
            xercesImpl
            2.10.0
        
        
            xml-apis
            xml-apis
            1.3.04
        
    
    
        src
        
            
                src
                
                    **/*.java
                
            
        
        
            
                maven-compiler-plugin
                3.3

Comment: can you provide your pom.xml

Comment: Yes, Please find it below.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with maven dependencies need to add few more maven dependency in the pom.xml file.

I had added to local repository and then imported to the pom.xml file. below is the cmd that I had used to install the particular jar that I had faced problem with

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jar file name.jar -DgroupId=mention your group Id-DartifactId=artifact Id that you want -Dversion=version number -Dpackaging=jar

These will install the jar file freshly then you need to go to eclipse and in maven local repository window need to update the index by right clicking it. then you can find in search the jar that is in local repository and add to the pom.xml file.

It work's